# Doesn't STL functions in C++ work properly for long long int?

Tags: c++, stl, long-integer

I have tried to use accumulate STL function for long long int data type. But it is showing garbage value in my compiler. But it works for int data type properly.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#define ll long long

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //vector<ll>v={1,2,3,4};
    vector<ll>v={10000000000,2,3,4};
    cout<<accumulate(v.begin(),v.end(),0);

    return 0;
}
```

It shows right output for the commented line. Is there any problem with long long int?

Answer (score 1):

Accumulator's type is deduced by the sum type. When you put 0 it is taken as 32bit and you got an overflow. To prevent this you need to give 0ll.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>
#include <stdint.h>

using ll = long long int;



int main()
{
    using namespace std;

    vector<ll>v={10000000000 ,2,3,4};
    cout<<accumulate(v.begin(),v.end(),0ll);

    return 0;
}
```

Also you should not use `#include <bits/stdc++.h>`. check stackoverflow for more explanation about it.

Also `using`  is better than `typedef` or `#define` for defining types.

Comment: The documentation at [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate#Common_mistakes) not only agrees with you, but also highlights (something close to) this as a "common mistake". ;)

Comment: Is this true only for accumulate or for other functions also? @JaMiT

Comment: @Nakib for many reducing functions the default value is int32. also accept the answer if it helps .

Comment: @Nakib ? I'm not sure how my comment could be applied to other functions, but I went ahead and searched cppreference.com for "common mistake". Based on that search, the page for `std::accumulate` is the only one with a "Common mistake" section, so in that respect my comment is true only for `accumulate`.

Comment: More generally, the type of `0` is `int`; it may or may not be 32 bits.